# Erro no PHP ... Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function modify() on boolean

Tags: php, php-7

Pessoal tenho um script em PHP que adiciona mais 10 dias em uma data.
O script estava funcionando maravilhosamente bem, porém, a alguns dias atrás comecei a receber o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function modify()
>   on boolean ... line 25.

A linha 25 referida no erro é essa:

```
$dt_mod1->modify('+10 days');
```

Aqui está o trecho completo relacionado a essa linha:

```
$dt_mod1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $dt_mod);
$dt_mod1->modify('+10 days');
$dt_mod2 = $dt_mod1->format('d/m/Y');
if ($dt_mod2 == $data_atual ){

    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE `cadastro` SET `situacao` = 'CANCELADA' WHERE `cadastro`.`codigo` = $codigo");
    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE `cadastro` SET `dt_mod` = '$data_atual' WHERE `cadastro`.`codigo` = $codigo");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente você passou um valor inválido para a função e não testou.

Idealmente seu código teria algo assim:

```
$dt_mod1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $dt_mod);
if ( $dt_mod1 ) {
   // faz o que tem que fazer
   $dt_mod1->modify('+10 days');
   $dt_mod2 = $dt_mod1->format('d/m/Y');
   // etc
} else {
   // Trata o erro
}
```

### Entendendo o problema

Veja este detalhe do manual, que eu marquei em negrito:

> Valor Retornado
>   Retorna uma nova instância de DateTime **ou FALSE em caso de falha**.

É o que acontece no seu caso, e `FALSE` não tem o método `modify`. Justamente por isso o erro mencionado.

Se quiser detalhes do erro, o PHP tem uma função que você pode por dentro do `else`:

```
if ( $dt_mod1 ) {
   // faz o que tem que fazer
   $dt_mod1->modify('+10 days');
   $dt_mod2 = $dt_mod1->format('d/m/Y');
   // etc
} else {
   echo 'Não foi possível a conversão: ';
   echo htmlentities( date_get_last_errors() );
}
```

Links para o manual:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.getlasterrors.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado pela ajuda. Percebi que eu havia feito uma modificação no código principal que gravava a data no formato às 'd/m/Y \à\s H:i:s' e me esqueci de modificar isso no código que estava 'd/m/Y H:i:s'.